# Trying to use GPIO pins of RPi4 while running object detection

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, object, raspberry-pi

I have trained my tensorflow lite model and working fine with webcam. Now, I want to use GPIO pins of RPI to turn an led ON when the "defective" item is detected with score between 95 to 99. I'm using EdgeElectronics [WEBSITE](https://github.com/EdjeElectronics/TensorFlow-Lite-Object-Detection-on-Android-and-Raspberry-Pi/blob/master/TFLite_detection_webcam.py) webcam code to detect my objects.

I prepared below code but couldn't implement the score logic.

I want turn on the led when the class object named 'defective' is detected and turn off led when class object names 'defective' is undetected.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

# Set up GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
LED_PIN = 11  # Replace with the actual GPIO pin you're using for the LED
GPIO.setup(LED_PIN, GPIO.OUT)

def turn_on_led():
    GPIO.output(LED_PIN, GPIO.HIGH)  # Turn on the LED

def turn_off_led():
    GPIO.output(LED_PIN, GPIO.LOW)   # Turn off the LED



while True:
   

    for i in range(len(scores)):
        if ((scores[i] > min_conf_threshold) and (scores[i] <= 1.0)):
            # ... (existing code)

            # Draw label

            object_name = labels[int(classes[i])]
            label = '%s: %d%%' % (object_name, int(scores[i]*100))

            # Turn on the LED when a "defective" object is detected
            if object_name.lower() == 'defective':
                turn_on_led()
            else:
                turn_off_led()

           


# Clean up GPIO
GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: Where is variable for scores?